# get first CLI argument after the options in shell scipt

Tags: shell-script, command-line, arguments

I have a script I class like so `gitploy up -t 2.0.0 test_repo`.  I pull out the "action" `up` right away, then I need to be able to get the `test_repo` before I process the options.  I don't want to lose that arguments in line, if that makes sense.. don't want to shift it away, just get it and let it be?  Basically I want to get that `test_repo` spot before I do

```
while getopts "zhvdurqw:c:i:e:o:b:t:f:p:g" opt; do
  case $opt in

    #flag----------------------
    h)
      usage;
      exit 0
      ;;
    #callback------------------
    c) queue_callback "$OPTARG"
      shift $((OPTIND-1)); OPTIND=1
      ;;
### so one and so forth
```

section of the script.  So basically I can do something like this

```
# i would get the first argument after the options here first so "test_repo" 
# would be a $@ or $* or something?
root_arg="test_repo"

while getopts "zhvdurqw:c:i:e:o:b:t:f:p:g" opt; do
  case $opt in

    #flag----------------------
    h)
      usage;
      exit 0
      ;;
    #callback------------------
    c) queue_callback "$OPTARG"
      echo "$root_arg was here"
      shift $((OPTIND-1)); OPTIND=1
      ;;
### so one and so forth
```

In a broader scope of this maybe the question I would guess is, **"How to get an arg by position relative to the options?"**

---

### revisal of question:

The hope is to say something like,

- positon of getopts output in command in var
- call the position of getopts output +1

  - `test_repo` argument is located +1 after getopts output
- do normal processing

I'm trying to not move the command for backward compatibility reasons to start with, but not really limited to that.  I figured I could just write a little shim here since I know the pattern is already set to `gitploy <__action> [__options] <__alias> [__remote_url]`.

I guess I could make everything an option and deprecate the other arguments.  Not sure that is a bad way to do this but it would seem that I would have to scan in an order to look for the `<__alias>` (or the `test_repo` as presented in the example) and look for it as an option such as `-a test_repo`.

Even if it is not the right way to do this in the end, I would like to have an answer on if you can "read the cursor" here and determine the argument value or if is an impossible thing to do.

## result of answer below

```
while getopts "zhvdurqw:c:i:e:o:b:t:f:p:g" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    esac
done

index="$((OPTIND))"
GD_REPO="${!index}";
OPTIND=1
```

This what I ended up doing.  Seems like dirty trick to fast-forward then rewind, but it works.  If there is better ideas, I would still love learn them.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand, but the way I've always done it is to put 'shift $((OPTIND-1))' (without OPTIND=1) after the while/getopt loop. Then $@ are the args after the options, $1 is the first arg after the options, etc.

Comment: Agreed. Do not `shift` until after the while loop. You're probably interfering with `getopts` by altering OPTIND this way

Comment: So I get `shift` will remove it, but still then I have all the options there and the question I think still remains, how do I say "get the repo_arg" in this `gitploy rm -t 2.0.2 -c test repo_arg` or `gitploy rm -t 2.0.2 repo_arg` or `gitploy rm -zvd -t 2.0.2 -c test repo_arg` before looping?  That is the question I'm trying to get to.  I need to know that argument before I loop through the options.

Comment: @mtklr isn't `$1` the first one after `gitploy` ? like `$1` on `gitploy rm -vds repo_agr` would be the `rm` ?

Comment: @glennjackman - `getopts` doesn't depend on the loop - it depends on `$OPTIND`. The asker is doing the right thing by resetting `$OPTIND` to 1 - which is the only way you can be sure `getopts` gets reset. The only problem there is you have to make sure when you do it that you do it at an argument boundary. So if you get a string of three options in an argument like `while getopts :xyz o -x -xyz -z; do echo "$o:$OPTIND"; done` `getopts` will loop a total of 5 times for the three args.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do now. It seems pretty tricky. If I needed a script that worked this way, I would try to arrange things to accept the arg in the test_repo position after the getopts. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: @mtklr I updated the question a little to better explain where I am at and what the end goal is here on the more personal end of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are logically contradictory. Given input like `gitploy up -t 2.0.0 test_repo`, you need to parse the options, and in particular notice the presence of the `-t` option and the fact that it takes one argument, in order to identify that the first non-option argument is `test_repo`.

So first **parse** the options normally. Then you can know what the first operand is. At that point, **process** the options. Store the information you need about the options in variables.

```
action="$1"
shift
unset t_arg
while getopts "zhvdurqw:c:i:e:o:b:t:f:p:g" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    c) c_arg="$OPTARG";;
    …
  esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
root_arg="$1"

if [ -n "${c_arg+1}" ]; then
  queue_callback "$OPTARG"
  echo "$root_arg was here"
fi
```

Comment: I can get what you are doing there.  that can be a super fallback, but I revised the question on where I am heading and the absolution question that would stop that path way.  Thank you for helping

Comment: @jeremy.bass I don't understand your “revisal”. What do you call “getopts output”? If that's the final value of OPTIND, you can't get it before it's been computed, and the way to compute it is to let the while loop run its course.

Comment: I meant how getopts is a function that returns, I presume, an array, but maybe there is a way to say because OPTIND is the index that you can infer the location, then go from there.  I'm throwing darts here honestly, but the intent is to try to read the line ahead of any processing as I need that value in almost all of those areas.  I am trying to think of a better way to approach this as well, but would like to duel work on this position detection problem as well.  Hope that helps clear it up. Thank you for the help

Comment: @jeremy.bass No, `getopts` doesn't return an array. It looks at one argument at a time, two if the first turns out to be an option requiring an argument. By the time `getopts` gets to `-c FOO`, it hasn't looked beyond `FOO`. If you want to read the line ahead of any processing, read the line by completing the `while getopts` loop, and then do the processing. And my answer shows a way to do that. Another way could be to do the loop, then reset `OPTIND` to 1.

Comment: so I could just to a quick while loop, [no case just empty while] just to move the index ahead, get the repo name, then reset OPTIND to 1 and do the real while loop with the case statements?

Comment: @jeremy.bass Yes, if you find it inconvenient to decouple the parsing from the processing, that's a viable approach.