# get command line agrument by variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, command-line, arguments

I want to get the arg of a command from a var that has the index in it of the arg that I want.  Something like this

```
# command in terminal, `foo -r -f value_wanted`
index="3"
var=$"$index"
echo $var ## expected output `value_wanted`
```

I know I can just call it by `$3` but that index I have is in the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the following notation:

```
echo "${!index}"
```

If you want to process positional arguments, I suggest to use `getopt` (not `getopts`), though.

Comment: perfect, that did what was expected.  Side note, this was to implement from http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257412/47672 , so I'm "fast-forwarding" the cursor in a way and getting the arg I need for the options, then rewinding it and doing the loop I need on the options.